# Best UI framework ( such as Material UI, or maybe another) for React based on your experience?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, frameworks, components

I want to use UI framework (such as Material UI, or Reactstrap, or something else, and I don't know which to use) with React. Can you help me with this question based on your experience? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very subjective question,
So the answer will also be subjective based on personal experience.

I have used material-ui, 
has most component pre-built, 
easy to use, 
easy to deploy,
good [documentation](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/)
and well maintain.

For customize component, you may try [styled-components](https://styled-components.com).

Answer (score 2):

Personally speaking, I am not a fan of [material-UI](https://material-ui.com/).

I use the most popular, minimal, customizable, intuitive React UI library, [**Ant Design**](https://ant.design/). The documentation is pretty easy to follow and to customize for your design system. It provides programmable functionalities that are customizable for your unique needs that I did not find in other UI libraries.

A new contender [**Chakra-UI**](https://chakra-ui.com/) is also very good.